# Quick Java SQL problem

Tags: java, sql

***My code:***

```
String sql = "SELECT Publisher.Name, Book.Title, ShopOrder.OrderDate, SUM(OrderLine.Quantity) AS No_Books, "
            + "SUM(OrderLine.UnitSellingPrice * Orderline.Quantity) AS Total_Price"
            + "FROM Publisher, Book, OrderLine, ShopOrder"
            + "WHERE OrderLine.BookID = Book.BookID AND ShopOrder.ShopOrderID = OrderLine.ShopOrderID AND Publisher.PublisherID = Book.PublisherID AND Publisher.PublisherID = " + id
            + "GROUP BY book.title, publisher.name, ShopOrder.OrderDate"
            + "ORDER BY ShopOrder.OrderDate, Book.Title";
```

**Resulting error:**

> syntax error at or near "Publisher" at char position 166 (Just after the FROM clause)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres spaces missing

Your strings is
...S Total_PriceFROM Publisher, Book, OrderLine, ShopOrderWHERE O...

You should use:

```
String sql = "SELECT Publisher.Name, Book.Title, ShopOrder.OrderDate, SUM(OrderLine.Quantity) AS No_Books, "
        + " SUM(OrderLine.UnitSellingPrice * Orderline.Quantity) AS Total_Price"
        + " FROM Publisher, Book, OrderLine, ShopOrder"
        + " WHERE OrderLine.BookID = Book.BookID AND ShopOrder.ShopOrderID = OrderLine.ShopOrderID AND Publisher.PublisherID = Book.PublisherID AND Publisher.PublisherID = " + id
        + " GROUP BY book.title, publisher.name, ShopOrder.OrderDate"
            + " ORDER BY ShopOrder.OrderDate, Book.Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you concatenate those strings there is no space between Total_Price and FROM.
And in other lines similarly. I always end and start a quoted SQL fragment with a space.

Answer (score 0):

You need spaces either at the end of your lines or at the beginning.  The resulting string would look like: `...AS Total_PriceFROM Publisher...`